# AS3: Is the "new SoundChannel()" allocation pointless?

Tags: actionscript-3, soundchannel

I see a lot of guides that do something like this:

```
var mySound:Sound = new Sound();
var myChannel:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel(); //unnecessary allocation?
myChannel = mySound.play();
```

Is allocating a new SoundChannel() in the second line completely unnecessary? From the docs, it seems that `Sound.play` generates a new SoundChannel every time, so you're not forcing it to use that SoundChannel that was just allocated, right? What the second line actually does is allocate a new SoundChannel, which does nothing, and assigns the variable myChannel to it. Then in the third line, mySound.play() generates a new SoundChannel and makes myChannel point to it instead, leaving the first SoundChannel inaccessible.

Should the second line just be this?

```
var myChannel:SoundChannel;
```

There are several guides which seem to do that unnecessary allocation, including an [example](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Sound.html#play()) in the official docs.

Comment: You don't need to create an instance of **SoundChannel**, there's no point to it, you get the valid one as the result of **Sound.play()**, that's correct.

Comment: Yes,  that first `SoundChannel` object you create is just thrown away/garbage collected after you assign `mySound.play()` to the `myChannel` var.   So indeed it is a complete waste to instantiate a new SoundChannel like that and is best avoided.